# Are hotels open to public?

Tags: hotels, etiquette

I am traveling to Shanghai and I heard that you can get a good view of the downtown from Ritz Carlton's roof and the source said it is a free alternative to the observatory decks on other buildings. Now I am curious, can you enter any hotel and go to any floor without having to book a room with them or anything? Are you able to just park your car and enjoy their amenities?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hotels are private property, but typically have areas open to the public, such as lobbies, restaurants, and bars. This depends greatly on the hotel: a 12-room roadside motel or a remote luxury resort is going to notice you sitting in the lobby fairly quickly and may not have any amenities open to non-guests, while a large urban hotel will have many people passing through and more public areas.

In the specific case of the Ritz Carlton Shanghai, there's the [Flair Rooftop Lounge and Restaurant](http://www.ritzcarlton.com/en/hotels/china/shanghai-pudong/dining/flair), described by its operators as "China’s highest rooftop bar." It looks like a nice [view](https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g308272-d1654265-i254103347-The_Ritz_Carlton_Shanghai_Pudong-Shanghai.html). There are a number of other [rooftop bars in Shanghai](http://www.timeoutshanghai.com/features/Bars_/27076/The-best-rooftop-bars-in-Shanghai.html) as well. Such facilities are for customers, and you'd generally be expected to purchase food or drink (at rooftop bar prices; you're paying for that view) to hang out there.

Comment: In many larger hotels you can't even get out of the lobby/public area without a room key.  Elevators often require the key to allow you to select a floor

Comment: @Midavalo If there are public areas like restaurants and bars (or even non-public but accessible areas like rooms for meetings and events), those floors are generally accessible even if the elevator requires a key to access guest rooms. You can always ask the hotel staff if you're unsure.

Comment: A tall hotel with a rooftop bar or restaurant usually has an express elevator to go there directly, without stopping at guest room floors.